# How to get DCOM Configuration permission?

Tags: c#, wmi

please help me to get

[image]

DCOM Configuration permission.

To get launch/access permission, I have used `DCOMperm.exe` but I am unable to get configuration permission.

Comment: What don't you understand about the user interface in your screenshot?

Comment: @TomW the screenshot only is the pointer of what information OP is talking about, he desires the get those information he highlighted by code.

Comment: @TomW I want to fetch configuration permission by using C#. Do you have any idea that how to get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added code below to fetch this data:

```
 using (DataTable comTable = new DataTable())
            {
                comTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AppId"));
                comTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
                comTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Local Service"));
                comTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Authentication Level"));
                comTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RunAsUser"));
                comTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Identity"));
                comTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Access Permissions"));
                comTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Launch and Activation Permissions"));

                comTable.DefaultView.Sort = "Name ASC";
                string query = ControlConstant.GETDCOMCONFIG;

                using (var moDisposer = new ManagementObjectDisposer())
                {
                    var managementObj = moDisposer.Search(query, msScope);

                    foreach (ManagementBaseObject dConfig in managementObj)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dConfig["Caption"])))
                        {
                            string szAppId;
                            DataRow row = comTable.NewRow();
                            szAppId = Convert.ToString(dConfig["AppID"]);
                            row["AppId"] = Convert.ToString(dConfig["AppID"]);
                            row["Name"] = Convert.ToString(dConfig["Caption"]);
                            row["Local Service"] = Convert.ToString(dConfig["LocalService"]);
                            row["Authentication Level"] = Convert.ToString(dConfig["AuthenticationLevel"]);
                            row["RunAsUser"] = Convert.ToString(dConfig["RunAsUser"]);
                            row["Identity"] = Convert.ToString(dConfig["RunAsUser"]);
                            row["Access Permissions"] = Utility.LaunchProcess(Utility.GetRootFolder() + "\\DComPerm.exe", "-aa " + szAppId + " list").ReadToEnd();
                            row["Launch and Activation Permissions"] = Utility.LaunchProcess(Utility.GetRootFolder() + "\\DComPerm.exe", "-al " + szAppId + " list").ReadToEnd();
                            comTable.Rows.Add(row);
                        }
                    }
                }
```